# Swapping video tags is making the entire div empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, janus-gateway

I am using JANUS to stream the video.

I have 2 div tags, one which is bigger than the other and I'm keeping an option to swap the elements. These div tags contain the video tags.
I have 2 video tags, one in which local video is being streamed and another in which the remote video is being streamed.
The following is the function I've attempted.

```js
var swappingVideoFunction = function() {

  var localVideo = $("#videolocal").html();
  var remoteVideo = $("#videoremote1").html();
  console.log(localVideo);
  $("#videolocal").html(remoteVideo);
  $("#videoremote1").html(localVideo);

}
```

I can see that in the html on inspecting, The video tag is present in the desired div but the video goes completely blank. The complete div looks empty. Is this the case with video tags in general? Is there an approach to do it?

Answer (score 1):

So my thinking is that the object your writing to could be updating the reference. This is why the JQuery clone() function comes handy to remove reference from the original object.

Check out the following code snippet.

```js
var swappingVideoFunction = function() {
  var localVideo = $("#videolocal").clone();
  var remoteVideo = $("#videoremote1").clone();
  $("#videolocal").html(remoteVideo.html());
  $("#videoremote1").html(localVideo.html());
}
```

```css
.green {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: contain;
}
.red {
  height: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: contain;
}

.swap-button {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="swap-button" onClick="swappingVideoFunction()">Do Swap</button>
<div id="videolocal">
  <video class="red" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="local.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="local.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
<div id="videoremote1">
  <video class="green" width="320" height="240" controls>
    <source src="remote.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="remote.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
</div>
```